# objective-c: failed to write image to documents directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm using this piece of code to try and save an image to the documents directory:

```
//FOR TESTING ON SIMULATOR 
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ReceiptImage1.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString* imageName = @"Receipt1Image1.png";
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];        
[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];

self.receiptImage1 = fullPathToFile;

self.receiptImageView1.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPathToFile];

NSLog(@"fullPathToFile %@", fullPathToFile);
```

However this piece of code doesn't set the imageViews image to the receipt image that I'm trying to write to the documents directory.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Did you check the return value of `writeToFile:atomically:`? If there is an error, you can check what it is by using the `writeToFile:options:error:` variant.

Comment: Also, why do you actually need to copy the image from the app bundle to the documents dir?

Comment: have you check your code in device?
because simulator doesn't executes the code line by line..[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO]; methode take some time to write the image to the path so try to load the image in image after some time

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Please checkout IBOutlet for receiptImageView1.

Comment: @MrTJ Once I'm successfully saving images to the documents directory I'll be changing the code to take an image from the camera / photos, this is just for testing on the simulator.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image:(NSString*)imageName{
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //convert image into .png format.

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory

NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]]; //add our image to the path 

[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)

NSLog(@"image saved");}
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly write the file atomically, then try:

```
self.receiptImage1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPathToFile];
self.receiptImageView1 = [UIImageView initWithImage:self.receiptImage1];
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not save to that path if there is already a file present.  (Check the API docs, I can't remember exactly.  But to be save you should add something like:

```
    NSArray *dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [dirs objectAtIndex:0];
    _exportPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFileName];  // may need to hang onto him

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_exportPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:_exportPath
                                                   error:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the following approach

```
-(void) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else {
        ALog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
    }
}
```

To save an image, simply do it like this:

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[self saveImage:yourImage withFileName:@"Your Image Name" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:path];
```

To load the image, implement this method:

```
-(UIImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {

    UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, extension]];

    return result;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
yourImage.image = [self loadImage:@"Your Image Name" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:path];
```

Or you could simply set your image equal to what this method returns instead of creating a method:

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
yourImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Your Image Name.png", path]];
```